# Can I disable or remove gnome-online-miners?

Tags: gnome3

### Background

I run Ubuntu Gnome 15.10. Almost every day there is a crash (due to some segfault) in `gom-media-server-miner`. So I looked up `gom-media-server-miner` and found [`gnome-online-miners`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineMiners) which is described as follows:

> GNOME Online Miners provides a set of crawlers that go through your
>   online content and index them locally in Tracker. It has miners for
>   Facebook, Flickr, Google, ownCloud and SkyDrive.

### Question

Can I disable the `gnome-online-miners` altogether? I don't want the feature.

### What I tried so far

I tried `sudo apt-get remove gnome-online-miners` and then it insisted on also removing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` which sounds like something I want to keep.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-online-miners 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-documents gnome-online-miners gnome-photos ubuntu-gnome-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 6 052 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Quick rant: I would rather not have some process try to crawl through something I don't want crawled. This is one of the reasons I am using Linux in the first place. So in a sense I am happy about the segfaults leading to crashes so I found out about the existence of this.

Comment: How did you disable these without removing useful programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered repeated SEGFAULTs with this package, and used this:

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -r gnome-online-miners
```

This command removes only the package and forces `dpkg` to treat any dependency errors as warnings.

I'm puzzled that this can't be done with `apt`/`apt-get` given that this package is `Priority: optional`.

gnome-photos, etc., still seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for that! I did not know about `--force-depends` before, so I learned more than how to solve this particular problem.

Comment: When I run `sudo apt upgrade` I still get an error. It then suggests I should run `sudo apt install -f`, which obviously fixes this error by reinstalling `gnome-online-miners`. Is it possible to just not execute this package, but keep it installed anyway? Or any other workaround...

Comment: Using 16.04 with gnome-shell

Answer (score 1):

You can remove package by following @tomas response. But you will still get an error each time you use `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install`.

`gnome-photos` and `gnome-documents` have a dependency to `gnome-online-miners`, even if they don't need it. A temporary hack that I found is :

- edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status`
- find the entry for `gnome-photos` and `gnome-documents`
- Remove `gnome-online-miners` from the field `Depends:`

You will need to apply this change each time `gnome-photos` and `gnome-documents` are updated.

Answer (score -1):

Could you just change the permissions on gnome-online-miners to make it non-executable? Or simply remove it from /usr/bin or wherever it is?